# Scss import only variables without styles

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

Scss Zurb-Foundation file _base.scss contain variables, mixins and some css code.
How can I import ONLY vars and mixins without styles?

Answer (score -1):

Use the source from Github to pick and choose what you'd like to import. Lately, I've taken to cloning [this directory](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/tree/master/scss/foundation), and using a Sass manifest file to import only the bits of Foundation that I need. You can get the full list of components to import [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zurb/foundation/master/scss/foundation.scss).

For example, in my manifest file I'll do something like

```
//
// Imports Foundation's variables and functions
//

@import "foundation/settings";

//
// Import individual Foundation components
//

@import "foundation/components/grid";
//@import "foundation/components/accordion";
//@import "foundation/components/alert-boxes";
@import "foundation/components/block-grid";
@import "foundation/components/breadcrumbs";
// ...
//@import "foundation/components/top-bar";
@import "foundation/components/type";
//@import "foundation/components/offcanvas";
@import "foundation/components/visibility";

//
// Import overrides and custom styles
//

@import "partials/my-custom-element"
```